# Write text files everyday

Tags: php

I just want to ask something. Is it possible to write a text file everyday?
Example is i want a text file that keeps all the records for this day only.
Thwn another new text file will be created tomorrow.
Is it possble in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and you also need cronjobs for it if you want to do that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for CRON jobs, you can create files with date in name, like `date("Ymd")."txt";` will create files like `20160628.txt` ..

```
<?php
  $filename = PATHTOFILE . date("Ymd") . EXTENSION;
  if(!file_exists($filename)) {
     //create a file
  }
?>
```

you can also use the same technique, but take advantage of [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and use just

```
<?php
  $filename = PATHTOFILE . date("Ymd") . EXTENSION;
  $handle = fopen($filename, "a"); //appends fwrite to the end of the file
  fwrite($handle, $string); //appends data in $string
?>
```

Comment: omg, I'd like to know why I got downvoted as this answer doesn't seem to be "bad"

Comment: hi sir,thanks for the information may i ask how will i save it as a txt file?and how can i save it inside a folder?so that it will have a separate folder that contails all txt files

Comment: `fopen` creates the file, if it's not present, `fwrite` writes content (and saves), at the end you can use `fclose` to finish file operations. to save as txt, just replace `EXTENSION` with `".txt"` and for the path, you can save it wherever you want, just create that folder and replace `PATHTOFILE` with the path to that directory

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cronjob wich executes an php file, you can set it up so it wil run every day. Your PHP logic can go in to this file.

If you like some more security you can generate a random key and send this like an get value to the file, first check if the get key equals the key set into the file and then do your logic

Comment: thanks i've already created a php script for my problem..and i think cronjob is more advisable if you are using linux. Anyway thank you